# Go - Using closures and adding maps to slices - filesystem.walk

Tags: dictionary, go, closures

In the following code I am trying to add file information to a map, which gets added to a slice. The slice contains a map for every file on the filesystem. My understanding is this is similar to how you would build an array of dictionaries in Python.

```
package files

import (
   "path/filepath"
   "os"
   "fmt"
 )

func GetFiles() {

    var numScanned int 
    var fileSlice = []map{}

    numScanned = 0 

    var scan = func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        numScanned ++ 

        var fileDetails map[string]interface{}
        fmt.Printf("%s with %d bytes\n", path,f.Size())
        fileDetails["filename"] = f.Name()
        fileDetails["filesize"] = f.Size()


        fileSlice = append(fileSlice, fileDetails) //Error =  cannot use fileDetails (type map[string]interface {}) as type string in append

        if err != nil { 
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s with %d bytes\n", path,f.Size())
        }
        return nil

    }

    directories := [] string {"C:\\"} 
    numOfDirectories := len(directories)

    for i := 0; i < numOfDirectories; i++ {
        err := filepath.Walk(directories[i], scan)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        }
    }   

    fmt.Printf("%d", numScanned)

}
```

Error:

```
c:\project\src>go run main.go
# files
C:\project\src\files\files.go:12: syntax error: unexpected ]
C:\project\src\files\files.go:14: non-declaration statement outside function body
C:\project\src\files\files.go:36: non-declaration statement outside function body
C:\project\src\files\files.go:37: non-declaration statement outside function body
C:\project\src\files\files.go:44: non-declaration statement outside function body
C:\project\src\files\files.go:46: non-declaration statement outside function body
C:\project\src\files\files.go:48: syntax error: unexpected }
```

I'm also trying to work out how closures work in Go, so I can add file details to a map which is added to a slice, which I can access after filesystem.Walk has finished.

Thanks

EDIT:

I updated the code but how do you make a slice of map?

Comment: The error says its all - `string` != `map[string]interface{}`. And additionaly you are shadowing `fileDetails`.

Comment: You can't put a map in a `[]string`, you're not initializing the map, and you're redeclaring the map within your `scan` function, shadowing the outer scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the code which leads to a new error. How do you make a slice of map? I spent a while looking this afternoon.

Comment: `foo := []map[string]interface{}{}`

Comment: @invisiblesun: Why are you using a map?

Comment: Im trying to store filesize, filename and filepath details in a map, and I'm appending each map to a slice. Once I've done that I want to convert the slice to json which is written to a json file.